# Estimated marginal means with afex::lmer - handling of random intercepts

Tags: lsmeans

I am fitting a very simple model where group, time and id are factors:

```
> model <- afex::lmer(depvar ~ group * time + (1 | id), data = df)

> model
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: depvar ~ group * time + (1 | id)
   Data: df
REML criterion at convergence: 684.9437
Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Std.Dev.
 id        (Intercept) 26.95   
 Residual              10.71   
Number of obs: 84, groups:  dSubjects, 28
Fixed Effects:
 (Intercept)        groupA         time2         time3  groupA:time2  groupA:time3  
     104.286       -11.643       -10.071        -5.214         3.643       -10.500  

> anova(model)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
            Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value   Pr(>F)   
group       203.53  203.53     1    26  1.7758 0.194229   
time       1703.02  851.51     2    52  7.4292 0.001452 **
group:time  754.93  377.46     2    52  3.2933 0.045013 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

When I use emmeans to calculate the marginal means, I obtain exactly the same means as if I would simply aggregate the original data df.

```
> emmeans(model, "group", by="time")
time = 1:
 group    emmean       SE   df lower.CL  upper.CL
 P     104.28571 7.751323 31.3 88.48290 120.08852
 A      92.64286 7.751323 31.3 76.84005 108.44567

time = 2:
 group    emmean       SE   df lower.CL  upper.CL
 P      94.21429 7.751323 31.3 78.41148 110.01710
 A      86.21429 7.751323 31.3 70.41148 102.01710

time = 3:
 group    emmean       SE   df lower.CL  upper.CL
 P      99.07143 7.751323 31.3 83.26862 114.87424
 A      76.92857 7.751323 31.3 61.12576  92.73138

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> aggregate(df$depvar~group*time,data=df,mean)
  group time df$depvar
1     P    1 104.28571
2     A    1  92.64286
3     P    2  94.21429
4     A    2  86.21429
5     P    3  99.07143
6     A    3  76.92857
```

Shouldn't the estimated marginal means from emmeans take into account the effect of the random intercept? I apologize if this is trivial as I am a novice with linear mixed models.